# Automation of [y/n] in Debian/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, automation, debian

I am writing a script file to automate. I am downgrading a Php version of the machine.
The command that I am using is interactive.

It will ask me three question which I need to respond to in the form of n/Y/q.

I know I can use `yes | {command}`.
But I need to give series of No,Yes,Yes.

How can I do that?

I even tried doing `echo " N Y Y" | command` but it's not working.

I am using Debian Wheezy.

Any help?

Comment: If this is a situation where `yes` would work otherwise, then Barmar's answer should sort you out. If it's a general automation question, `expect` is nice. But if this is related to APT/dpkg, it's worth pointing out that the relevant utilities have several of their own methods of automation. Look into `debconf-set-selections` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put newlines between each answer:

```
printf "N\nY\nY\n" | command
```

Answer (score 2):

You need new line character '\n':

```
echo -ne 'N\nY\nY\n' | command
```

Failing that you can use expected which was already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much. I dont know what -ne flag does. But it did magic in my case.I tried to do without -ne flag then it was not working.So then I added -ne flaf and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo N Y Y | xargs -n 1
```